# Using wget to download comma delimited file from web source

Tags: html, unix, wget

I am looking to retrieve a series of text files from the following webpage:

http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VAAH/2013/06/13/DailyHistory.html

I would like to automate the retrieval in UNIX using the 'wget' command on a series of files that this page points to (at the bottom of the page, the "Comma Delimited File" link), for example:

http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VAAH/2013/06/13/DailyHistory.html?format=1

However, when attempting to use the following argument:

'wget http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/VAAH/2013/06/13/DailyHistory.html?format=1'

UNIX comes back and says 'wget: No match."

Possibly this is due to the '?format=1', but I am not sure. Is there any way to retrieve the file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I forgot the quotes. So if anyone else is having this problem, just use

wget " [your address] "

rather than

wget [your address]